# Understanding hollow waveguides. What is $\lambda_g$ on the figure?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, fiber-optics

I am trying to understand the field distribution in waveguides.

On the figure is $HE_{12}$ mode of hollow fiber.

What is the $\lambda_g$ ? Is it $\lambda_g$ = $\lambda_0$ / $n_{eff}$.
Does the z field component repeat (circles) many times (L/$\lambda_g$) over the length L of the fiber ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lambda_g$ is the wavelength inside the waveguide. Yes, that pattern repeats itself all along the waveguide - and it propagates at a velocity that is less than the velocity of electromagnetic waves in free space.